# Angularjs - How to override browser's Back button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My web app is currently using Angular, I cannot show the code because it's classified but I will describe it: On the left side column is a list of link that I can click on it and content will be showed on the right side. Because of that, my page (I'll call it INDEX page) just have 1 state.

Problem is when I click on some links on the left side and press the browser's back button to go back to the previous link (still on INDEX page), it broke my page's CSS.

Do anyone know a method to override the back button so I can call my own function to go back, something like that: `$scope.on('browserBack', function() { $scope.goBack(); })`

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: excuse me, I cannot get your idea, my URL is not changed when I click on the link, so I think I cannot use the $location

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. Well, it depends how you did implement the update of the right column, and what you even mean by "broke the CSS". Can you try to debug the problem first, and try to figure in what way the page is actually broken? There are not by chance style sheets loaded just in time with the content, so they might depend on always loading the entry page first?

Comment: Sorry for reply late, "broke the CSS" mean (I think) the css could not loaded when press the back button: the layout is broken, text color is changed, pictures is resized to original size, etc.